# JQuery effect working in firefox; not chrome / ie

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

This problem surprises me because it does not work in Chrome as well. Chrome!!
  Anyways, I have 3 select boxes, A, B, C.  On a page load, B and C are hidden. (This is fine in all browsers).  Currently, I have an event handler attached to specific values in box A, so that if a value is clicked, B shows itself populated with results according to A.  Same thing for C: if a value in B is clicked, C will show itself.
  However, this "show" effect only occurs in firefox -- Chrome and IE are confused.

Any suggestions? hints?
  Here is some code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#B").hide();
    $("#C").hide();
    $('select#A option').each(function() {
        $(this).click(function() {
               $.getJSON(stuff, callback(data));
           });

    });

});
function callback(data) {
    // alert("hi");  // This isn't working for Chrome / IE! so the callback isn't called
    $("#B").show();  // This isn't working for Chrome / IE!
};
```

EDIT: It Turns out, the 'select#A option' -- the 'option' tag was the buggy one. After changing my handler to "change", I was able to debug and debug till I just removed the option tag -- everything seems to work now.

Thanks,
Michael

Comment: does the ajax query arrives to the server?  would an alert() at the start of callback() work?  and after the $("#B").show()?

Comment: Sounds like the stray comma issue somewhere in your code. To verify look for the following regexp pattern: /,\s*[\]\}]/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The actual problem is in the following line:

```
//...
$.getJSON(stuff, callback(data));
//...
```

You are not passing the callback function, you are actually executing the function and passing `undefined` since it doesn't return anything.

You should pass only the reference of the function:

```
//...
$.getJSON(stuff, callback);
//...
```

Or use an anonymous function in place:

```
//...
$.getJSON(stuff, function(data){
  $("#B").show(); 
});
//...
```

**Edit:** I haven't noticed about the click handler that you're trying to assign, I recommend you to use the [change](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change) event on the select element, to ensure that an option has been selected:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#B,#C").hide();

  $('select#A').change(function() {
    $.getJSON(stuff, function(data) { $("#B").show();});
  });
});
```

Comment: +1 for the callback i didn't see, but even without a call to $.getJSON it looks like the click is still not picked by IE or Chrome

Answer (score 2):

I think that you might have extra closing brackets at the end of the callback function.

**UPDATE:**

It seems like firefox can pick the click event for the option but not IE. i don't know for chrome but it might be the same problem. Instead of listening to the click event on the option you could just use the [change](http://docs.jquery.com/Events/change#fn) event to track a change in the select.

you could do the following if the change event does correspond to what you are trying to do.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#B").hide();
$("#C").hide();
$('select#A').each(function() {
    $(this).change(function() {
           $.getJSON(stuff, callback(data));
       });

});
```

});
function callback(data) {

```
$("#B").show();
```

};

Notice how i am listening to the change event on the Select itself.
I hope this helps!

Comment: Is it possible that the callback doesn't get called? did you debug the javascript code with firebug to see if the callback function get called?

Answer (score 0):

If you put an alert in your callback function does it get shown?